# SQLZoo White Christmas self join on date

Tags: sql

Say we have a dataset called `hadcet` that has historical temperature data in the format:

```
+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| yr   | dy | m1   | m2   | m3   | m4   | m5   | m6   | m7   | m8   | m9   | m10  | m11  | m12  |
+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 2001 |  1 |   40 |   11 |    9 |  112 |   87 |  131 |  185 |  180 |  150 |  151 |   91 |   98 |
| 2001 |  2 |   77 |   32 |   -4 |  114 |   99 |  126 |  207 |  163 |  168 |  143 |   99 |   29 |
| 2001 |  3 |   52 |   66 |   -3 |   84 |  105 |  100 |  209 |  166 |  153 |  142 |   87 |   55 |
| 2001 |  4 |   50 |   57 |    5 |   69 |   72 |  130 |  219 |  151 |  134 |  139 |   90 |   73 |
| 2001 |  5 |   47 |   68 |   12 |   71 |   82 |  136 |  217 |  161 |  139 |  159 |   75 |   82 |
| 2001 |  6 |   43 |   83 |   57 |   90 |   76 |  135 |  201 |  173 |  141 |  142 |   95 |   46 |
| 2001 |  7 |   49 |   85 |   86 |   69 |   90 |  110 |  185 |  161 |  153 |  128 |  112 |   62 |
```

And so forth, for all the days, months and years between 1772 and 2017.

Let's define a "White Christmas" as the temperature on December 25th being less than zero.

Write a query that shows the number of White Christmases a person would have been exposed to during their childhood per birth year. We'll define childhood as being between 3 and 12 inclusive assuming they were born at the beginning of the year and were about 1 year old on their first Christmas. Only show years where a child born that year would have experienced 7 or more White Christmases.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.yr, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.yr) AS wcc
FROM 
    hadcet a
    JOIN hadcet b ON b.yr > a.yr + 2 AND b.yr < a.yr +11
WHERE b.m12 < 0 AND b.dy = 25 
GROUP BY a.yr 
HAVING wcc >= 7
```

However, the query doesn't run [in the SQLZoo editor](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/White_Christmas) on the webpage with this problem (problem #4). Is this a valid solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution is tagged as *Correct answer* by SQLZoo :

```
SELECT 
    x.yr,
    COUNT(y.yr) wcc
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM hadcet
) x
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT yr FROM hadcet WHERE dy >= 21 AND dy <= 25 GROUP BY yr HAVING SUM(m12 < 0) > 0
) y ON y.yr >= x.yr + 2 AND y.yr <= x.yr + 11
GROUP BY x.yr
HAVING COUNT(y.yr) >= 7
```

The query uses two subqueries :

- `x` lists distinct years
- `y` selects White Christmas years only

Then the outer query joins the subqueries using the childhood logic.

NB : the definition of a White Christmas given in your post does not correspond to the one on SQLZoo : *We declare a White Christmas if there was a day with an average temperature below zero between 21st and 25th of December.* You need to use that rule to get the expected results.